# Fit the text in text object when passing the values from parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I have text object in which I am passing parameter value (names) in this form:

Name1, Name2, Name3.... Name n

The problem I am facing is the fitting inside that object, so I have a situation like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name1, Name2, Name3.......................................................Name m,
Name m+1, Name m+2...............................................................
.................................................................................
.................................................................................
...........................................................................Name n
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, there is that white space in the right (right from Name m and Name n) side and I am not sure how to handle that. So the problem is fitting in one row.

Comment: Did you embed the parameter field in the text object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the parameter field is a string, do the following:

- create a formula field `{@names}`
- enter the following text:

  ```
  Join({?parameter_field}, ", ")
  ```

- add this field to the details section; mark it `can grow`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I just set "Justify" option in horizontal aligmnet and it works. Off course, before that, I also checked "Can Grow" option.